# Dropdown menu don't know what to do

Tags: html, css

im new here, and i really need help about dropdown menu. The thing is that i want dropdown menu only when i move cursor on jewlery, but when i move cursor on jewlery or decor or art it shows dropdown menu everywhere. Thanks in advance!  [Image how looks mine version of dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGHSE.png)
[And this is original how should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy1W5.png)

```css
body{
 background:#ffffff;

/*===========
         Main
============*/   
}
#main{
 margin:0 auto;
 width:1500px;

}
/*============
          Header
=============*/

#header{
 padding:13px 0;
    float:right;
 text-indent:100%;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
#logo{
 padding-bottom:30px;
}
.dropdown{
 display:inline;
 float:right;
 list-style:none;
}


.submenu {
 z-index:9999;
 background-color:white;
 border:2px solid #6d6e70;
 text-align:center;
 }

.dropdown li{
 float:left;
 padding-top:40px;
 text-align:right;
 width:125px;
 list-style:none;
}
.dropdown a{
 font-size:16px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#6d6e70;
 outline:none;
 border-right:1px solid;
 padding-right:35px; 
}
   
#slide{
 display:block;
 margin:auto;
 clear:both;
 
}
#slider {
 display:block;
 left:290px;
 position:absolute;
 top:39%;
}
#slider1{
 display:block;
 right:290px;
 position:absolute;
 top:39%;
}
#text-box{
 background:#ffffff;
 border:2px solid #6d6e70;
 clear:both;
 width:930px;
 height:140px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:75px;
 margin:auto;
 color:gray;
 margin-top:20px;
}
#footer{
 clear:both;
 width:1400px;
 padding-top:50px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#copy{
 float:left;
 clear: both;
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
 font-size:11px;
 color:#7b7c7d;
}
#mid h5{
 text-align:center;
 clear: both;
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
 color:#868688;
 font-size:16px;
    margin-left:85px;

}
#social-links ul{
 display:inline;
 clear:both;
 text-align:center;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
#social-links li{
 display:inline;
 
}
#social-links a{
 display:inline;
 height:25px;
 width:25px;
 float:right;
 padding-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

 
 <title>Uhsome</title>
 <link href="styles/Reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="styles/Base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<style>
.li a {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 40px;
 width: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 
}


.submenu{
 margin-top:75px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 175px;
    min-height: 15px;
}

.submenu a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
}


</style>
<body>
<!--     

MAIN

-->

<div id="main">
<!-- 


HEADER

 -->
    <div id="header"><a style="padding-right:15px">login</a> <a style="padding-right:15px">my cart(3)</a> <a style="padding-right:15px">search..</a> </div>

<div class="dropdown">
<ul>

<li>
  <a href="#">jewelry   </a>
  <ul class="submenu">
   <li><a href="#">necklaces</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bracelets </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">rings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">pendants </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
  
  <li><a href="#">   rugs   </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">   furniture   </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">   decor   </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">   art   </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">   apparel   </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">   beach   </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">   gifts   </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">   services</a></li>
  
 
  </div>
   <img id="logo" src="Images/Logo.jpg"  height="87px" width="208px">
  </div>
  <!-- 
  
  SLIDER 
  
  -->
  <div id="slider" >
     <a  href="#"></a>
  <img id="shape1" src="Images\shape1.jpg" width="90px" height="70px">
</div>
  
  
  <div id="slider1">
     <a  href="#"></a>
 <img id="shape1_copy" src="Images\shape1_copy.jpg" width="90px" height="70px">
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
  
  
          <img id="slide" src="Images/Main.png" width="1100px" height="500px">
   
   
    <div id="text-box">
  <h1>Everything You Love</h1>
 </div>
 
      <div id="footer">
       
    
   <div id="copy">
       © 2016 HAN design. All rights reserved. Built by Uhsome
   </div>
   
       <div id="mid">
    <h5>customer service</h5>
    <h5>our company </h5>
    <h5>contact us</h5>
    </div>
    
   <div id="social-links">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com" target="top"></li>
     <img src="Images/google_plus.png" width="35px" height="25px">
    </a>
                
    <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="top"></li>
     <img src="Images/twitter.png" width="30px" height="30px"/>
    </a>
    
    
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="top"></li>
     <img src="Images/facebook.png" width="15px" height="30px"/>
    </a>
    </ul>
   
   
   </div> 
    
    </div>
    
 
  
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have all the links present inside `dropdown` class. Instead `dropdown` class should only be used with `jewelry` link.

Try doing this:

```
<ul>

<li>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">jewelry   </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">necklaces</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">bracelets </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">rings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">pendants </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#">   rugs   </a></li>
<li><a href="#">   furniture   </a></li>
<li><a href="#">   decor   </a></li>
//add rest 
</ul>
```

Comment: I just did. Have a look at my answer, and find the difference between your code and mine, you will know.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you so much!

Comment: If it worked for you,please accept my answer by clicking on the tick.

Comment: Okay okay, im new at this, need to figure out how this works.